# Flipbox backside buttons not clickable on Safari Mac OS when flipped vertically

Tags: html, css, css-grid, css-transforms

It's only flip boxes set to flip vertically that I cant click the links/buttons on the back to navigate/un-flip. If its horizontal links/buttons on the backside of the flip box are clickable. Was a problem on the Wordpress site it was built on, and remains and issue on codepen in trying to recreate the problem.

Working examples (flipping in all directions) here:
https://codepen.io/scotosaurus/pen/mdzrRBP

I was trying to use `display:grid;` to avoid absolute positioning of elements to keep everything more versatile, but thats a new approach for me.

It's only on Mac OS Safari that I've found this issue. Chrome on Mac OS and both chrome and Safari on iOS work fine.

Im sure it will be obvious to someone else, but im stumped.

EDIT:
It's I've tested on coworkers Macs and it's only an issue in Safari 16.4 for Mac. (14.1.12, 15,4, 16.3 all perform as expected)